# IFTTT webhooks maker basic authentication

Tags: webhooks, ifttt

Creating an ifttt applet to call a web service api. But failing if i use username and password in the url.

Anyone passed username and password in wehooks ifttt?

Answer (score 1):

It should work with http://username:password@example.com

Alternatively you could use a secret key var that is checked in the script if it keeps failing for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily implement and use IFTTT on  your website by using this NPM package: **ifttt-webhooks-channel**

I implemented it by using the following:

```
const IFTTT = require('ifttt-webhooks-channel');

const ifttt = new IFTTT('your key goes in here as a string');
```

Then when you have added IFTTT and your key to your node application, you can post to the webhook by using:

```
ifttt.post('ContactformUsed', [
    firstName,
    email
]);
```

*You can add the post request to any callback function you have in your web application*

The string "ContactformUsed" is the name of the webhook (The one you use to idendity the specific webhook you have made. This is a webhook name you choose on ifttt's website). The above example is a post request to a webhook i made, that will give me a notification with the firstname and email of the person using the contact form on my website.

If you would like to read a bit more detailed about IFTTT and how to implement it on your website, then i have made an article here: 
https://themikeandersen.com/blog/how-to-send-notifications-from-your-website-through-ifttt

Comment: Noted, I will do that :) I am still new here so I am still learning the lingo in this forum.